# How do you sync the "Saved Games" and "Picture" folders with OneDrive?

Tags: windows-8.1, sync, onedrive

I have Windows 8.1 installed, which includes OneDrive natively. It automatically syncs some things such as `Camera Roll`, but I really want to sync other user folders:

- Pictures (not just Camera roll)
- Saved Games

I'm not sure how to go about this, is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

It used to be possible with older versions of OneDrive (Windows Live Mesh), but that functionality was removed.  Now, there is no way to do it.